# why the syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this:

```
# other stuff...
print str(checksum)+" "+ranswer+".0000000000"
```

giving syntax error in Python 3, even though it works fine in Python 2.5 ?

ADDED:

Could anybody tell me what is the equivalent of `strip(something)` in python 3?

Thanks,its fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

print is a function in Python3. Use it is `print(...)`There is not anything called `strip(something)`. But what you might looking for is `strip() method on string objects'. It is available in Python3.

```
strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> str

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

And you use it like this:

```
>>> '   Philando Gullible   '.strip()
'Philando Gullible'
>>> 'aaaXXXbbb'.strip('ab')
'XXX'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, print is a function, not a keyword.

do this: `print(str(checksum)+" "+ranswer+".0000000000")`

Comment: Thanks could you please check my added query?

Comment: If you're looking for the strip() method on strings, then it's still there.  Otherwise, I'm not aware of a strip function.

Comment: I've answered you're original question, how about accepting my answer?  If you have additional questions, perhaps ask them separately.

Comment: This is ridiculous!!!!! I posted 12 min before the other answer, then the poster added more to his question.  And I didn't get my answer accepted.

Comment: I have +1-ed your answer and I feel Senthil Kumaran answers both of my precisely very well.Thanks.

Comment: Fine, but I don't like how you waited until *after* I answered your question to add another question, then someone else comes flying in to answer the second part (not that I blame Senthil at all).  I answered your first question precisely.  If you want to ask another one after your first question was *already answered*, you should have started a new post.